# error in onDraw function in android?

Tags: android, overriding, ondraw, android-gesture

I have implement the `onTouchListener`, error on `onDraw` function in this class i put the capital letter and small letter on first of function name dost not clear, it displayed

remove @override annotation

```
public class bsdselect extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
static String items;
static String items1;
static String dates;
static String finalDate;
int a,r,g,b;
ListView lv;
TextView text1;    
String COLOR;
String GRPNAME;
String QTY ;
String BUDGET;
String STOCK;
String DIFF;
String DIFF_P;
TextView title;
//protected Activity context;

/* JSON Node names */
private static final String TAG_JSONDataResult = "JSONDataResult";
private static final String TAG_GRPNAME = "GRPNAME";
private static final String TAG_QNT = "QTY";
private static final String TAG_BUDGET = "BUDGET";
private static final String TAG_STOCK = "STOCK";
private static final String TAG_DIFF = "DIFF";
private static final String TAG_DIFF_P = "DIFF_P";
private static final String TAG_COLOR = "COLOR";    
// contacts JSONArray
//JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bsdselect);
    //lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listbsd);
    title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    items=b.getString("item");
    items1=b.getString("item1");
    dates=b.getString("date");
    String topic=items+"/"+items1;
    title.setText(topic);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = dateFormat.parse(dates);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);
    torun();

}

public void torun() {
    String myUrl;
    myUrl = String.format("http://192.168.2.16/RestServicebsd/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/?Location=%s&GROUP=%s&asondate=%s",items.replaceAll(" ","%20"),items1.replaceAll(" ","%20"),finalDate);
    // String url0 = "http://192.168.2.16/RestServicebsd/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/?Location=Arihant Wanarpet&GROUP=ArihantShowroom&asondate=2013-2-24".replaceAll("","%20");

    // Hashmap for ListView
    // final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
     // getting JSON string from URL

    try {

        JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(myUrl);
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        JSONArray list = json1.getJSONArray(TAG_JSONDataResult);


        // looping through All Contacts
        JSONObject c = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){    
            c = list.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable

            GRPNAME = c.getString(TAG_GRPNAME);
            QTY = c.getString(TAG_QNT);
            BUDGET = c.getString(TAG_BUDGET);
            STOCK = c.getString(TAG_STOCK);
            DIFF = c.getString(TAG_DIFF);
            DIFF_P = c.getString(TAG_DIFF_P);
            COLOR = c.getString(TAG_COLOR);


            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(TAG_GRPNAME, GRPNAME);
            map.put(TAG_QNT, QTY);
            map.put(TAG_BUDGET, BUDGET);
            map.put(TAG_STOCK, STOCK);
            map.put(TAG_DIFF, DIFF);
            map.put(TAG_DIFF_P, DIFF_P);
            map.put(TAG_COLOR,COLOR);



            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            dataList.add(map);
            c=null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_Exit:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
            //Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public   void MyCustomView(Context mContext){
    //...
    //Your view code
    //...
    onZoom();

    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getBaseContext(), new ScaleListener());
}

private void onZoom() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {  TAG_GRPNAME, TAG_QNT, TAG_BUDGET, TAG_STOCK, TAG_DIFF, TAG_DIFF_P, },
            new int[] {
                     R.id.l2, R.id.l3, R.id.l4, R.id.l5, R.id.l6, R.id.l7}){
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View v = convertView;
             if (v == null) {
                 LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
             }

                   text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.l7);
                   String rgbColor=  dataList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR);
                   String[] ARGB = rgbColor.split(" ");     
                   a=Integer.parseInt(ARGB[0]);
                   r=Integer.parseInt(ARGB[1]);
                   g=Integer.parseInt(ARGB[2]);
                   b=Integer.parseInt(ARGB[3]);                       
                   text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
                   return super.getView(position, v, parent);
          }

     };


            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
     v.invalidate();
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    //...
    //Your onDraw() code
    //...
    lv.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

       // v.invalidate();
        return true;
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: So, remove the annotation if it says so..

Comment: @CRUSADER after removed it displayed The method onDraw(Canvas) of type bsdselect must override or implement a supertype

Answer (score 0):

If it is not showing any other error and only showing remove `@override`, then remove that and try running it.

Comment: if i remove that it display error The method onDraw(Canvas) of type bsdselect must override or implement a supertype